# Zeroing out low signal pixels in a fits file using python

Tags: python, fits, astropy

I am trying to write a simple script that will read in a fits image file, set all pixels that are below a certain threshold (that I will feed in based on background statistics) to zero or nan. I have included below the code that I am using. This writes a new fits file that resembles the original, but the pixel values seem to be re-scaled (ie, I would expect the minimum value in the new file to be the minimum that I specified, but that is not the case). I THINK that its an issue with how I am writing a header to the new file, but have no idea how to fix it, and would welcome any suggestions or snippets for astronomers who have done similar things. Thanks!

```
import astropy.io.fits as fits
import numpy as np

f=fits.open('filename.fits')
data = f[0].data
header = f[0].header
data[data<noise_cutoff]=np.nan
fits.writeto('outfilename.fits', data, header)
f.close()
```

Comment: The snippet you've shown looks correct.  Can you read the file back in and test whether the min/max (`np.nanmin`, `np.nanmax`) are what you expect?

Comment: min/max will be what I expect using the code above if I set to zero, not if I set to nan. I think some kind of pixel scaling parameter. Weirdly enough, adding in the line (data=data) before writing the new fits file seems to fix the problem

Comment: Unrelatedly, but if you want to open an existing FITS file and update some bits in the data it's easier to just do `h = fits.open('infilename.fits'); h[0].data # Do something to the data...; h.writeto('outfilename.fits')`.  No need to awkwardly use `fits.writeto`.  Also if you don't need the original data you can make in-place updates even faster by opening the file in write mode.

Comment: Meanwhile the question about scaling is probably related to http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/appendix/faq.html#why-is-an-image-containing-integer-data-being-converted-unexpectedly-to-floats

Answer (score -1):

In python 2.7 I've always done it like this:

```
img[numpy.where(img<min_flux)]=0
img[numpy.where(img>0)]+=add_flux
```

See the difference:

This returns actual values of the fields which meet the condition:

```
>>> data2[data2>noise_cutoff]
array([ 0.15600586,  0.15576172,  0.16992188, ...,  0.15063477,
        0.21899414,  0.15722656], dtype=float32)
```

This returns indices where the condition returns `True`:

```
>>> np.where(data2>noise_cutoff)
(array([   0,    0,    0, ..., 1488, 1488, 1488]), array([  88,  789, 1065, ..., 1683, 1833, 1872]))
```

You want to set the values at indices to nan or zero, I don't know how the first one is interpreted as, but from experience I know it doesn't work.

**edit** 
I also have bad experience with FITS viewers handling nan values. Usually people write a fits field i.e. `RANGE` which should describe all your possible values. I've often seen `[0, 65535]` but it's mostly a thing of agreement and type of data (it's FITS format after all).

I also got curious about the differences between sending indices and values and this is what I did:

First to show some default values:

```
>>> data
array([[ 0.01800537,  0.00421143, -0.01644897, ..., -0.03686523,
         0.05981445, -0.00924683],
       [-0.00267029, -0.02334595,  0.03179932, ...,  0.09436035,
         0.05981445,  0.00457001],
       [-0.13354492, -0.0302124 , -0.00266266, ...,  0.05291748,
        -0.06445312,  0.09436035],
       ..., 
       [ 0.04669189, -0.02218628, -0.06347656, ..., -0.01507568,
         0.10229492,  0.02636719],
       [ 0.00536346, -0.00842285,  0.04669189, ..., -0.00816345,
         0.00565338, -0.02886963],
       [-0.07043457, -0.00840759, -0.09106445, ...,  0.06787109,
        -0.11865234, -0.05645752]], dtype=float32)
```

I made a copy as not to edit the original file I need, then I acted with `data2[data2>noise_cutoff]` and `np.where(data2>noise_cutoff)` and copied the results, with a bit of editing so it's a valid expression, into the `[ ]` operator.

```
>>> data2 = data.copy

# result of data2[data2>noise_cutoff]
>>> data2[[0.21899414,  0.15722656]]
array([[ 0.01800537,  0.00421143, -0.01644897, ..., -0.03686523,
         0.05981445, -0.00924683],
       [ 0.01800537,  0.00421143, -0.01644897, ..., -0.03686523,
         0.05981445, -0.00924683]], dtype=float32)

#result of np.where(data2>noise_cutoff)
>>> data2[[0,0, 0, 1488, 1488, 1488], [88,789,1065,1683,1833,1872]]
array([ 0.15600586,  0.15576172,  0.16992188,  0.15063477,  0.21899414,
        0.15722656], dtype=float32)
```

So it seems that numpy likes to unpack the argument sent to `[ ]`. In example, sending `data2[[1, 2]]` would return first and second row of `data2`. Since I've sent in float values `0.21899414` and `0.15722656` they obviously get cast as `int`s, get rounded down to `0`, and I got 1st row returned twice.

Sending in a `data2[[1],[1]]` however returns a float at `data[1,1]`. Sending in a list for both of those returns a series of values written at those indices i.e: `data2[[1,2], [1,2]]` gets you elements `[1,1]`, `[2,2]`

```
>>> data2[1,1] == data2[[1],[1]]
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Aren't astropy and python2 not compatible?

Comment: @usernumber :This is a 3 year old answer, at the time it supported it. Still does for a little while: `Astropy v2.0 now repaces v1.0 as the long term support release, and will be supported until the end of 2019. The next major release of Astropy (scheduled for January 2018) will only support Python 3.x. `